# How to get all unimplemented methods using TypeElement

Tags: java

I have a method that receives `TypeElement` object. This object could be holding either interface or abstract class. Either one of them could extend or implement another interface.

How to get all unimplemented methods of the type element I have including its superclasses and interfaces? And also ensure that each method is listed only once?

P.S. Sometimes methods are declared in interfaces then declared again in abstract classes.

Scenarios

```
abstract class A { ...methods... }
interface B{ ...methods... }`
abstract class A implements B,C { ...methods... }
abstract class A extends B { ...methods... } // B is an abstract class
interface A extends B,C { ...methods... }// B & C are both interfaces
```

Comment: Use an IDE. I like netbeans, but eclipse is good too.

Comment: IDE? How is this answer correlated to my question ? I need to get a list of methods in runtime...

Comment: [This appears to be related.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27948358/1079354) Long story short:  reflection alone isn't going to be able to do that.  You'd need to access the AST.

Answer (score -3):

You can use Reflection API, for example BMW implements Car, similarly it can be any implementation of Car and given below `getDeclaredMethods()` will give all the methods, Similarly `getSuperclass()` which will provide the parent there are many methods to get the necessary details

```
public class Reflection {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car car = new BMW();
    Class rental = car.getClass();
    try {
        Method[] declaredMethods = rental.getDeclaredMethods();

        System.out.println("Declared Methods are: "

        + Arrays.toString(declaredMethods));

        for (Method dmethod : declaredMethods) {

            System.out.println("method = " + dmethod.getName());

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

}
```

Kindly let me know if this answers your problem

Comment: Any specific reason for the vote down ? If you feel the proposed solution contradicts the objective of OP then kindly share it

Comment: 1. This is not good, atleast when someone is taking the initiative to help, taking the effort of creating a structured solution and trying to provide the best possible solution that the posting person knows
2. if it doesnt address the solution at least have the decency of providing the reason rather than demoralizing the efforts. 
3. Nevertheless, this is a lesson for me to not help people in future.